# Opening port 80 for outbound SMTP causing timeouts for apache

Tags: apache-2.2, smtp

I have a (dv) Dedicated Virtual at Media Temple running Parallels/Plesk.

Following [this instruction](http://forum.webhostingdevelopment.com/how-to-add-custom-smtp-port-in-plesk/), I was able to open an additional port and configure use of port 80 for use as SMTP outgoing mail server. My client travels frequently and they have found many ISPs blocking port 25 and 587 and are frustrated.

This is working great, outbound email requires authentication but is sent successfully using port 80. BUT, now Apache is non-responsive when I try to access the domain. It just hangs. Presumably the mail server has picked up the request before Apache can.

I would like to continue to use port 80 for outbound email, as port 80 is open almost everywhere. Any ideas how I can keep it open for SMTP *and* route/tunnel to Apache (or vice versa) so that both can use port 80?

Here is the contents of the file I created at /etc/xinetd.d/smtp_alternate:

```
service smtp
{
    service         = smtp_alternate
    type            = UNLISTED
    port            = 80
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    wait            = no
    disable         = no
    user            = root
    instances       = UNLIMITED
    env             = SMTPAUTH=1 SHORTNAMES=1
    server          = /var/qmail/bin/tcp-env
    server_args     = -Rt0 /usr/sbin/rblsmtpd -r sbl.spamhaus.org /var/qmail/bin/relaylock /var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd /var/qmail/bin/smtp_auth /var/qmail/bin/true /var/qmail/bin/cmd5checkpw /var/qmail/bin/true
}
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems to confuse incoming and outgoing traffic.

You can't run more than one (type of) server listening on the IP address and port - that's how clients know where to connect. Apache is not unresponsive - if it's running at all, it can't see the traffic coming in on port 80 because your mailserver is using it.

Your first port of call should be your ISP to find out what incoming ports are not blocked.

Failing that you could try 443 if you're not already using HTTPS, 42 if you're not running a DNS server, 110 if not running pop3, 143 if not running imap, then try some port numbers above 1024.

Comment: Thanks! I had just tried 443 but appears I need to disable SSL in Apache first. We aren't using encryption anywhere, so that might be the way to go.

Comment: This answer was very useful for me. I didn't try using 80 but both of my ISPs block port 25 traffic. I switched POP3 and IMAP ports. A little unconventional but works and IMAP is much better for general purposes these days.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is a web server that is bound on port 80. You have setup an SMTP server on port 80.  The only solution is to use another port for STMP that you are 100% sure won't be used by anything else.

The tutorial you link to sets things up on port 2525.  Why not use that?

```
service smtp
{
    service         = smtp_alternate
    type            = UNLISTED
    port            = 2525
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    wait            = no
    disable         = no
    user            = root
    instances       = UNLIMITED
    env             = SMTPAUTH=1 SHORTNAMES=1
    server          = /var/qmail/bin/tcp-env
    server_args     = -Rt0 /usr/sbin/rblsmtpd -r sbl.spamhaus.org /var/qmail/bin/relaylock /var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd /var/qmail/bin/smtp_auth /var/qmail/bin/true /var/qmail/bin/cmd5checkpw /var/qmail/bin/true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 2525 ought to work, I just thought if I could route traffic through an existing port (that the ISPs would not have blocked) it would be easy for my clients to jump from ISP to ISP without chancing an overprotective ISP or router configuration that may block nonstandard ports.. that was my line of thinking anyway. My clients travel across the country and so there's no way of knowing where they may be using internet

Comment: Your logic makes sense—wanting to assign a port that is known to work—but generally mixing ports like this never works. And—I can tell you from my experience—port 80 can get blocked as a server from many ISPs who want to prevent end-users from running servers on their home network connections. Good luck!